# Show drop down menu onmousedown without loosing onclick functionality

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onclick, focus, onmousedown

I try to get a drop down menu to work as most drop down menus seem to work, i.e. as soon as the mouse button is pressed on the trigger the drop menu shows up. Seems rather easy with some css and javascript but it turns out to be a bit tricky.

The obvious way would be this:

```
<script>
    function toggle(id) {
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        el.style.display = (el.style.display === 'none') ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
    }
</script>
<input type="button" value="click me" onmousedown="toggle('menu');"><div id="menu" style="display: none">Menu</div>
```

Unfortunately this is not exactly it, since now it is no more possible to navigate to the trigger with the tab-key and hit enter to show the menu. Seems that this needs the menu to show with `onclick`. But adding the `toggle` function to onclick as well shows the menu at `onmousedown` and then collapses it when the mouse button is released at `onclick`. Is there a way to stop `onclick` from firing when `onmousedown` was firing before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this would work fine for your requirement

```html
<script>
    var lastEvent = '';
    function toggle(id, event) {
        event = event || window.event;
        if (lastEvent === 'mousedown' && event.type === 'click' && event.detail > 0){
            lastEvent = event.type;
            return;
        }
    
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        el.style.display = (el.style.display === 'none') ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
        lastEvent = event.type;
    }
</script>
<input type="submit" value="click me" onmousedown="toggle('menu', event);" onclick="toggle('menu', event);">
<div id="menu" style="display: none">Menu</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/safeer/rzg7sahb/18/

Comment: Working for Chrome, but not working in Firefox it seems

Comment: Thanks. That explains it then. I am using Firefox. I'd prefer a solution working in all browsers.

Comment: @Daniel Modified the code to work on cross-browsers (works in Chrome, Firefox, and IE)

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work. A shame I have to add a global variable.

Comment: Just realized that this solution has a little snag. If you trigger the `onmousedown` event and hold the button pressed the menu will open. However, if one (without releasing the button) moves away from the button, then `lastEvent` will retain the `mousedown` value. Hence the next `onmousedown`/`onclick` event will not hide the menu as expected.

Comment: Updated the code, and it's not that hard to figure-out the logic, if you take a look at the event object properly.

Comment: Thanks seems to work. Sorry for not figuring it out myself. I am still new to javascript and only a free time programmer. But it was a nice shared work. I figure out the problems and you the solutions. I'll try to make myself familiar with the event object property now.

Answer (score 0):

try adding onclick event and submit your form using its name

```html
<input type="submit" value="click me" onmousedown="toggle('menu');" onclick="document.getElementById('form_name').submit();" >
```

Comment: What form? Is it misleading that I use `type="submit"` on my input? I only want to trigger the menu to show nothing else.

Comment: If you want to show the menu so why not using an other div rather than a button? Or try using `<button type="button">clickMe</button>`?

Comment: For what it is worth I have changed the type of the input to a `button`.

Comment: With the type button you dont need to use preventDefault, because the form wont be submitted if there is one

Comment: There is no form involved whatsoever.

Comment: so what is the functionality you don't want to lose for onclick event ?

Answer (score 0):

whats about this method?

```
<script>

function toggle(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
}

function activate(e){
    alert(e.id);
}
</script>
<div id="menuWrapper" onmousedown="toggle('menu');"onmouseup="toggle('menu');">
   <div id="mainlink" >Click Here</div>
   <div id="menu" onmouseup="activate(this);" style="display: none">Menu</div>
</div>
```

[JS fiddle with div for menu opener](https://jsfiddle.net/rzg7sahb/16/)

Comment: No, this is also not the normal menu behavior, since the menu is shut down when the button is released. Also, as far as I see it, there is no possible opening of the menu with keys.

Comment: Oh ok, i thought you would like to get this behavior. Sorry.

Comment: Has it to be plain javascript or would you also use jquery ?

Comment: I'd prefer plain javascript. I marked an answer that seems to deliver what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that seems to work:

```
<script>
    function toggle(id) {
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        el.style.display = (el.style.display === 'none') ? 'inline-block' : 'none';
    }
</script>
<input type="submit" value="click me" onmousedown="toggle('menu');" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode === 13) toggle('menu');" onkeyup="if (event.keyCode === 32) toggle('menu');">
<div id="menu" style="display: none">Menu</div>
```

It emulates the normal key behaviour. Although I am not fully sure that it emulates all of it and in the right way on all operating systems.